# Android Broadcast Receiver in Service

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver, telephony

I'm trying to make service that will do something each time phone call is ended. My problem is that service doesn't receive any broadcasts. 
I've implemented it like that:

```
    package com.kubasienki.spedycja;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;

/**
 * Created by kuba on 11/4/2015.
 */

    public class FirstService extends Service {

        private static String TAG = "kurwa";
    final BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();
            if(action.equals("android.provider.Telephony.CALL_STATE_IDLE")){
                Log.v("kurwa", "skonczono");
            }
            else if(action.equals(android.telephony.TelephonyManager.ACTION_PHONE_STATE_CHANGED)){
                Log.v("kurwa", "???");
            }
            else {
                Log.v("kurwa", "??!!!?");

            }
        }

    };

        @Override
        public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            super.onStart(intent, startId);
            Log.d(TAG, "FirstService started");


            IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
            filter.addAction("android.provider.TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE");
            filter.addAction(android.telephony.TelephonyManager.ACTION_PHONE_STATE_CHANGED);


            registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
            //this.stopSelf();
        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroy() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onDestroy();
            Log.d(TAG, "FirstService destroyed");
        }

    }
```

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.kubasienki.spedycja" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar.FullScreen" >
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
        <activity android:name="com.kubasienki.spedycja.MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <service android:name=".FirstService" ></service>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

And starting service :

```
startService(new Intent(this, FirstService.class));
```

Comment: using `Log.v("kurwa",` is not a good practice, better use a `TAG` like this: `private final static String TAG = "kurwa";`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perrmissions were in the wrong place.

Answer (score 1):

> Create a broadcast which listen for Call

```
class CallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {//do want you want
    }
}

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS" />  
 <receiver android:name=".CallReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

[Handling Phone Call Requests the Right Way for Users](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2013/05/handling-phone-call-requests-right-way.html)

Comment: still nothing i've made class as you've wirtten and then used it like `final BroadcastReceiver receiver = new CallReceiver();  IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
            filter.addAction("android.provider.TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE");
            filter.addAction(android.telephony.TelephonyManager.ACTION_PHONE_STATE_CHANGED);


            registerReceiver(receiver, filter);` in my service class

Comment: Can it be connected to paused state of app when user dials? @Vishal

Comment: whenever you make a call CallReceiver Broadscat will get notify

Comment: but should i register that class from my service if it's registered in manifest??

Comment: i am getting notify each time i am making a call . you don't need to add ..final BroadcastReceiver receiver = new CallReceiver(); IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(); filter.addAction("android.provider.TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE"); filter.addAction(android.telephony.TelephonyManager.ACTION_PHONE_STATE_CHANGED); registerReceiver(receiver, filter);

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94246/discussion-between-vishal-gaur-and-kuba-sienek-sienkiewicz).